# GnuPG package: Difference between pgp and gpg

Tags: linux, gnupg, pgp, gnu

I feel there's a not much of general user friendly content on the internet about GnPG and it's utilities. At least I couldn't find any to my satisfaction. It's probably because people (except developers ) do not prefer to indulge and verify their package after downloading. 
The articles have come across so far only implies that there's no difference between gpg and pgp yet I can't use the pgp command after installing the gnupg package.
What package do I need to run pgp if it's not included in the gnupg package ?

Comment: Did you read `man gpg` already? I'm not even sure there is an official "pgp only" package for linux, pgp's proprietary commercial software

Comment: Took me sometime to response I was actually confused with the pgp and gpg commands. But I got the difference/similarity  now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the `gnupg` package, then it's binary is called `gpg`, but about the general difference between pgp and gpg... I'll use a few quotes from a few sources:

> gpg is the OpenPGP part of the GNU Privacy Guard (GnuPG). It is a tool to provide digital encryption and signing services using the OpenPGP standard. gpg  features  complete  key management  and all the bells and whistles you would expect from a full OpenPGP implementation.

[from `man gpg`]

---

> PGP can refer to two things:
>
> 1. The Pretty Good Privacy software originally written by Phil Zimmermann, and now owned by Symantec.
> 2. The formats for keys, encrypted messages and message signatures defined by that software. These have now been formalised as the OpenPGP standard.
>
> The GPG software is an independent implementation of the OpenPGP standards, so you can use it to exchange encrypted messages with people using other OpenPGP implementations (e.g. Symantec's PGP).

[[source at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/186814/129271)]

---

> ### gpg vs pgp and OpenPGP
>
> Used both to encrypt files in place and prepare them to be sent securely over the Internet, **gpg** is related to, but not the same as, **pgp** and **OpenPGP**. While gpg is based on the OpenPGP standards established by the IETF, it is — unlike pgp — open source. Here's the rundown:
>
> - OpenPGP is the IETF-approved standard that defines encryption technology that uses processes that are interoperable with PGP.
> - pgp is Symantec's proprietary encryption solution.
> - gpg adheres to the OpenPGP standard and provides an interface that allows users to easily encrypt their files.

[[source](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3293052/linux/encypting-your-files-with-gpg.html)]

---

> ### Development and Licensing
>
> Phil Zimmermann wrote PGP under the GNU General Public License. At one time it could be freely used and modified. However, Zimmermann eventually converted PGP into paid-license software. Symantec purchased the rights to PGP in 2010. The company now manages the licensing of PGP as part of its Enterprise products division. The developers of GPG essentially recoded PGP, maintaining all its features, and released it again under the GNU General Public License, meaning that the code can be modified, used and freely distributed. GPG remains free, as of the date of publication.

[[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226012556/http://www.ehow.com:80/info_12225332_difference-between-gpg-pgp.html)]

Comment: Welcome :) But StackExchange doesn't generally like comments that only say "thanks", it seems a little impolite but they would clutter up the site with lots of  "thanks"'s everywhere. It's best to [accept the answer (click the check-mark) if it seems best, &/or up vote it too (if you're able)](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have less than the required reputation to able to vote.

Comment: I've upvoted the Q, but it does take a bit more yet. However, selecting a correct answer should be available now, and that gives +2 rep too (as long as it's not your own answer). I even found [an image of the checkmark to the left of answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png), thanks :)

Comment: Oh yeah I can see it now. I accepted the answer. This is my first time so please ignore any clumsyness from my part.

Comment: No problem, the help center ("?" link in the top right on the website) has a lot of interesting stuff. It looks like the checkmark got un-selected? I saw it was there earlier, but now it's gone... clicking the check mark a second time un-selects it (that's a feature to pick a different answer, usually a better answer if one shows up in the future).

Comment: `gpg is the OpenPGP part of the GNU Privacy Guard (GnuPG)`. Wait a minute, so gpg does not stand for "Gnu Privacy Guard"?

Comment: acronyms are quite the rabbit hole to dive down, sometimes with basic meanings, or silly ones, or none at all